# Why is select not signalling a file descriptor with buffered data?

Tags: c, select, linux-kernel, posix, nonblocking

I have a server program that uses `select` with a 10 second timeout to wait for activity on several non-blocking client connections. Each time the `select` call signals that there's input to read, the server will read and process up to 1K of data. If there's a response to send, it will send it. Then it will go back to `select`.

```
fcntl(clientFd, F_SETFL, fcntl(clientFd, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);
while (true) {
  FD_ZERO(&readfds);
  FD_SET(clientFd, &readfds);
  timeout = (struct timeval){.tv_sec = 10};
  select(clientFd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
  if (FD_ISSET(clientFd, &readfds)) {
    uint8_t recv_buffer[1024];
    fread(recv_buffer, 1, 1024, clientFile);
    // process & maybe respond / fflush
  }
}
```

Client messages range from small (10 or 100 byte) messages to large (3-10K messages). Clients will wait up to 30 seconds for a response before hanging up. When they hang up, they send a small 10 byte hangup message.

A scenario is playing out that is breaking my understanding of how `select` is supposed to work. A client sends a message that is smaller than the read buffer, so the server reads the whole thing and responds. Then the client sends a 3K message. The server reads the first 1K and then subsequent `select` calls time out. I expected `select` to return immediately and signal that there's data available if the kernel had data buffered for that file descriptor. After the client times out, it sends a hang-up message. When the hang-up message arrives, suddenly the server is able to `select` that file descriptor and it reads the second and third chunk of the client's larger message followed by the client's smaller message.

I'm very certain of the timing of these events due to (1) the long timeouts involved, (2) a tcpdump of the conversation confirming that the 3K message arrived as a single TCP segment.

A simple demonstration program using `pipe` does not exhibit this behavior, nor does another simple demo using a TCP socket. So I must be doing something silly in the server program. What should I be checking for?

I'm checking that:

- The client's read FD is in the read FD set prior to the select
- Whether the client's read FD is in the read FD set after the select (it isn't)
- Size of read data (always 1K if at least that much is available)
- Whether a second call to `fread` would block (It doesn't. I tried in the debugger and I also did a different run with the `recv_buffer` sized to 4K which read the entire 3K message)
- The packet fragmentation (none) via `tcpdump`

[image: wsd]

Comment: `fread` is a **buffered** I/O function. You've given up all control. You have no idea how many bytes are really being read from the underlying file descriptor. You can try using `setvbuf` to make your file unbuffered.

Comment: you should probably use read() and actually check the return value of select.

Comment: @n.m. I had not considered that `fread` would buffer internal to `libc` and not be using the kernel's buffer.

Comment: @Huckle Oh, my mistake.  I shall remove the comment.  I tend to use poll most of the time over select and misread the manual.

Comment: You then have to ask yourself what `fread` does differently from `read`, and why on god's green earth it exists in the first place.

Comment: To be fair, I don't think `select` is the current recommendation anymore. It's just that I haven't gotten around to investigating alternatives yet.

Comment: I normally use poll() for no real reason.  I don't think there is any problem with select(), though.

Comment: @n.m. Well the obvious difference is the `FILE *` argument instead of a file descriptor. Annoyingly, the man page doesn't mention the buffering behavior. Nor does [opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

Comment: Welp, that's on me for not reading the footnotes. There's a topic elsewhere that mentions that standard I/O streams may be buffered. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05

Comment: @Huckle for these types of operations, you will rarely want to use stdio functions.  You will normally use read(), write(), send(), recv() and/or a few other related ones.  The stdio functions are really for files and work okay for ttys sometimes.

Comment: @n.m. Confirmed that `setvbuf` or switching to `read` both resolve the symptoms. Why don't you throw that comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Posting what @n.m. said. Will take down if they post their comment as an answer:

> `read` is a **buffered** I/O function. You've given up all control. You have no idea how many bytes are really being read from the underlying file descriptor. You can try using `setvbuf` to make your file unbuffered. – n.m.